# Is there any way to run Cucumber tests from parent folder of features folder?

Tags: cucumber, directory, git-bisect

I am trying to run a `git bisect` while using our automated tests to check the commit if it is the one causing the defect. The structure of our program is:

```
app
  - cucumber_tests
    - features/
      - main_features/
    - cucumber.yml
  - src/
```

Obviously this is not the default/standard folder structure for running Cucumber tests as you would want the `features` folder to be at top-level of your app. **This was not my choice and cannot be changed**.

I can run the tests by `cd` into `cucumber_test` and then run. *However*, in order to run `git bisect` it must be done at same level as the `.git` folder.

My question is: is there a way to run the Cucumber tests from a parent directory of the `features` folder in Cucumber? Being able to read the `cucumber.yml` file would also be very beneficial.

Is there a way to tell Cucumber that you are not using the standard folder structure?

**Edit:** I have been able to get the tests started by using `cucumber -r cucumber_tests/features cucumber_tests/features/main_features/first.feature`. However, it is unable to find some of the step definitions part-way through the test.

It appears that cucumber is looking for files in `app/features` not `app/cucumber_tests/features`

Comment: I thought you might just be able to do `cucumber -r cucumber_tests/features cucumber_tests/features`, but in my brief experiment that didn't work.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth I am still trying different combinations with the `cucumber -r` command. I was able to get the tests started but it was unable to find some of the step definitions.

Comment: Glad you got farther than me. Might help to add your progress to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the same folder structure. But you need to change the parameters in order to run your features. Otherwise this will not load step definitions. I hope you have step definitions inside the features folder. So now use this command to run the features: `cucumber -r <absolute path of the features folder[C:\users\xyz\project\some_folder\features] absolute_path_feature_file[C:\users\xyz\project\some_folder\features\example.feature]`
This way you cucumber will load your step definitions even if you have a different folder structure.